# Can you play PSP games on a PS3 (without hacks)?

Tags: ps3, psp

Is it possible to play a game PSP bought from the Playstation Store *without* a PSP?

Also, is it possible to hook a PSP up to your PS3, and if so, can you play games on the PS3 with the PS3 controller?

Finally, is it possible to hook your PSP directly up to your TV and play games that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Not to my knowledge as it currently stands unless the game ALSO states its playable on the PS3

2) I assume you want to hook the PSP up to the PS3 to play the PSP game on the PS3 with the PS3 controller, This is also a No (You can remote in to a PS3 and play games on the PS3 that stream to your PSP... But I so far only have done this with games I have purchased digitally like Wild Arms 3)

3) The Slim PSPs (rev 2000, 3000) have a cable you can buy that allows you to play the games on a TV (Go search Amazon.com and Id suggest the Sony cables).

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear but...thank you! The most important piece was the information on that only certain PSPs only me to hook up to a TV.

Answer (score 4):

What James said above is correct. It is also important to note that if you decide to purchase any "mini's" from the Playstation Network Store, those can be played both on PS3 and PSP despite being made for the PSP.

Comment: Thanks for the information - and welcome to Gaming.SE :)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add some more information in addition to the other answers...

The PSP Go can also connect to a TV. Plus it supports control via a Dualshock 3 controller, although I believe you have to use a PS3 to set up the connection.

The only PSP games playable on both PSP and PS3 are the **downloadable PS1 classics** and the **Minis**. I am not sure if it is possible to copy the saved games between the two platforms though. Regular PSP titles cannot be played on PS3.

Comment: I'll be getting a (free) PSP Go any day now. After I source a video output cable I'll be able to try out the TV-out and Dualshock combination. Just like a proper console, only much more portable!

Comment: Be interesting to see if you get it to work.

Comment: @Wipqozn: It works! Really well, actually. Main issues are that you need to use a PS3 to set up the bluetooth pairing, and if you re-pair the controller with the PS3 (like would happen if you charged it using the PS3's USB port), you have to re-pair it with the PSP Go again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and has been done but only with CFW and mods, I play almost all my PS3 games on my psp and vise versa. Anywhere I have wifi I can play ps3 games from my psp. If your PS3 is running 3.55 firmware you can easily do it by installing a CFW among other things, if your ps3 didn't come with 3.55 firmware you have to downgrade your system by means of soldering (some models cant do this either).

Basically with each PS3 model that comes out... more functionality is taken away. If you have a newer PS3 sell it and get the old FAT model (80gb with 4 usb is best as it can run every hack with no issues and it came with FW 3.55, it can also be downgraded by software means instead of soldering the hardware).

Comment: You've missed thew asker's points completely - he asked for a way to play PSP games on his PS3, and a way to do it without hacks